# SQL Order By causing big run times

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have the following query. When I remove the Order by statment at the bottom of the query it runs in a few seconds.

When I add in the order by statment in can take a couple of mins.

Is there anything obviously wrong with this query that would make it slow?

```
SELECT     TOP (10) addedBy, contactName, title_name, title_short_description,     private, Art_medium, Artist_collection, Art_permanent_collection, dateEntered,  dateModified, 
title_translated_description, weblink, type, start_date, end_Date, Subcategory,  title_art_description, id, title_name_translated, translated_short_description, pickDate, 
pickOfTheMonth, event_periods, other_categories, rating, cnt, Artists_represented,  city, country, county, district, latitude, longitude, openingTimes, Short_description, 
sub_categories, venue_address1, venue_address2, venue_Name, venue_translated_name,  title_id, venue_id, isLive, venueLive, tags, invite_only, featured_venue, 
translated_description, venue_addedBy
FROM       tblTitle_popular AS title
WHERE      (id NOT IN (SELECT TOP (91) id
                       FROM   tblTitle_popular AS title
                       WHERE  (0 = 0) 
                       AND    (start_date >= '27-Jan-2012') 
                       AND (start_date <= '31-Dec-2999') 
                       AND (isLive = 1) 
                       AND (venueLive = 1) 
                       AND (private <> 1 OR private IS NULL)
                       ORDER BY pickOfTheMonth DESC, pickDate DESC, featured_venue DESC, start_date, city)) 
AND (0 = 0)
AND title.start_date >= '27-Jan-2012'
AND (title.start_date <= '31-Dec-2999')  
AND (title.isLive = 1) 
AND (title.venueLive = 1) 
AND 
(title.private <> 1 OR title.private IS NULL) 
/* 
ORDER BY title.pickOfTheMonth DESC, title.pickDate DESC, title.featured_venue DESC,  title.start_date, title.city
*/
```

Comment: Probably some missing indexes.

Comment: `id NOT IN (SELECT ... >>> ORDER BY ... <<< )` is unnecessary, but it is probably ignored.

Comment: You could try using `ROW_NUMBER` to do this pagination. @biziclop - This is SQL Server or sybase and the `ORDER BY` is there to specify the `TOP`. `@James` - Please specify RDBMS and version and include the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on SQL Server 2005 + (as you are using `TOP` with parentheses) you could try

```
WITH title 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY pickOfTheMonth DESC, 
                                             pickDate DESC, 
                                             featured_venue DESC, 
                                             start_date, 
                                             city) AS RN 
         FROM   tblTitle_popular 
         WHERE  ( start_date >= '27-Jan-2012' ) 
                AND ( start_date <= '31-Dec-2999' ) 
                AND ( isLive = 1 ) 
                AND ( venueLive = 1 ) 
                AND ( private <> 1 
                       OR private IS NULL )) 
SELECT addedBy, 
       contactName, 
       title_name, 
       /*Other Columns*/
       venue_addedBy 
FROM   title 
WHERE  RN BETWEEN 92 AND 101 
ORDER BY RN
```

Please upload the XML version of the actual execution plan if you want suggestions to improve the performance of your existing query.

Answer (score 0):

`Order by` in any db makes a query longer. Seeing that there are 2 `Order by` statements in your query i would suggest building some indexes based on those.